# Cluster items by condition and order using linq

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I want to cluster some numbers by condition and their order in the list.

```
int delta = 3;    
var numbers = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 9, 6, 3, 2, 7, 7, 4, 1, 9, 1, 2 };    
var g = numbers.GroupBy(n => n <= delta);
```

This gives two groups based on the condition. What I want is:

```
g1: 2
g2: 4, 9, 6
g3: 3, 2
g4: 7, 7, 4
g5: 1
g6: 9
g7: 1, 2
```

**edit**
The condition is to group them based on a condition (here it is number <= delta), but every group should only contain numbers that are next to each other in the first list.

Comment: I don't understand what the actual condition is. How did you come up with that result?

Comment: I'm editing to clarify it.

Comment: it's not group by, it's making several lists in some defined order

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the logic, you want to create a new group whenever item `n` passes the condition but item `n - 1` fails, or vice-versa.

Well, normally you wouldn't use Linq for such a thing. You'd have to iterate over the loop one item at a time and build the result set by yourself. For example:

```
List<int> list = null;
var result = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();
bool? prev = null;
foreach (var n in numbers)
{
    bool cur = n <= 3;
    if (prev != cur)
    {
        list = new List<int>();
        result.Add(list);
        prev = cur;
    }
    list.Add(n);
}
```

But here is a workable solution in Linq. It depends upon site-effects, which you should normally avoid:

```
var prev = numbers.First() <= delta;
var counter = 0;
var result = numbers.GroupBy(n => (prev != (prev = n <= delta)) ? ++counter : counter)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: agreed, using linq here makes this overly complex... just create a list of lists.

Comment: Side effects within LINQ operators don't really play nice.

Comment: "normally you wouldn't use Linq for such a thing" That's a great note!

Answer (score 3):

So what we are conceptually doing here is going through the list and grouping while a condition is met.  We can write a corresponding operation just for that without too much difficulty:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

We can now write:

```
var groups = numbers.GroupWhile((prev,next) => 
    (prev <= delta) == (next <= delta));
```

Here the condition for when to start a new group is when the previous item's comparison is the same as the current item's.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, but I'm getting the idea. Thank you.

Comment: @odyodyodys Well, it was "working" in the sense that it did what I wrote it to do; I've now adjusted it now that you've clarified your problem, which is slightly different than what this was coded to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a fan of `fold` you can write it this way:

```
var groups = numbers.Skip(1).Aggregate(new List<List<int>>(new[] { new List<int> { numbers[0] } }), (acc, b) =>
{
    if ((acc.Last().LastOrDefault() <= delta) == (b <= delta))
    {
        acc.Last().Add(b);
    }
    else
    {
        acc.Add(new List<int>() { b });
    }
    return acc;
})
```

Here groups is of type of `List<List<int>>`